# Fetching Objects from the Database don't work in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a problem when i use the find() method in symfony :

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't10.id' in 'on clause'

It's only with a specific Entity , with the others this is working perfectly.

Here my code :

```
$classeId = $_POST['classeid'];
                $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Classe::class);
                $classe = $repo->find($classeId);
```

and my entity :

```
 <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ClasseRepository")
 */
class Classe
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Formation", inversedBy="classe")
     */
    private $formation;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Calendar", mappedBy="classe", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $calendar;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\person", inversedBy="classes")
     */
    private $responsable;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFormation(): ?Formation
    {
        return $this->formation;
    }

    public function setFormation(?Formation $formation): self
    {
        $this->formation = $formation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getCalendar(): ?Calendar
    {
        return $this->calendar;
    }

    public function setCalendar(?Calendar $calendar): self
    {
        $this->calendar = $calendar;

        // set (or unset) the owning side of the relation if necessary
        $newClasse = $calendar === null ? null : $this;
        if ($newClasse !== $calendar->getClasse()) {
            $calendar->setClasse($newClasse);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getResponsable(): ?person
    {
        return $this->responsable;
    }

    public function setResponsable(?person $responsable): self
    {
        $this->responsable = $responsable;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I searched the error but most post say its because the primary key is not id but in my case the primary key is id. I tried also to fetch object with the method findBy() and use other parameters than the id but i got the same error.
My full code :

the class : http://www.pastebin.com/r7hREPYD , the repository : http://www.pastebin.com/Mp118dQt , the controller : http://www.pastebin.com/q29UnyGd

Comment: Is your database up to date / is the table created?

Comment: @Jeroen yes of course

Comment: Can you run php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate ? As the error shows in the ON clause there might be something wrong with the relations.

Comment: Isn't `getManager()` missing after `getDoctrine()`? In Symfony 4, you don't do that anymore though...

Comment: Ok i got a error message when i run php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate . Now its ok the command tell me : [OK] The database schema is in sync with the mapping files. But i still got the same error when i use the find() method to fetch objects.

Comment: @Preciel in the documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database . They don't use getManager() . And the same method is working with my other entity .

Comment: since the error message states that it doesn't know `t10.id` it suggests, that the error happens on some *deep* joins. (querybuilder usually increments the alias numbers it gives the tables in the query, starting from t0, ...). it is very likely, that t10 isn't the classe table/entity at all.

Comment: then can you provide a bit more of your controller please? I don't think your error is where you think it's. It's most likely on a `JOIN`.

Comment: `$calendar = new Calendar();
                    $calendar->setStartDate($_POST['start']);
                    $calendar->setEndDate($_POST['end']);
                    $calendar->setEvent($_POST['event']);
                    $classeId = $_POST['classeid'];
                    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Classe::class);
                    $classe = $repo->find($classeId);
                    $calendar->setClasse($classe);` @Preciel

Comment: Edit your question instead of using comment to complete your code @mohasalim

Comment: @Preciel its done

Comment: can you also add a screenshot of the error thrown plz? (trying to isolate the line where the error happen)

Comment: @Preciel https://imgur.com/a/I248hje

Comment: I meant the error thrown by Symfony (this page full of red)

Comment: @Preciel https://imgur.com/a/G09lVwl

Comment: A long screenshot to see what is under in hte Exception log plz (writing a replay ATM, a lot of things aren't right in your code)

Comment: @Preciel https://imgur.com/a/G09lVwl i updated with all the screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error come from bad associations with the entity. So i deleted the entity and all associations and re create the class and now its working.

Answer (score 1):

Try find with `namespace`:

`$classeId = $_POST['classeid'] ?? 1;`

**OR**

`$classeId = $request->request->get('classeid', 1)`; //By default your id = 1

`$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(App\Entity\Classe::class)->find($classeId);`

And have you update your `database`:

`doctrine:schema:update`

after this try again.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you hadn't to use $_POST directly, but you have to use Request like that.

```
public function foo(Request $request): void {
   $classId = $request->request->get('classId');
   $classe = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Product::class)
        ->find($classId);

   ...
}
```

Maybe your unsanitized id is the problem.

You can try to write a method with the repo of the class as a formal parameter.

```
public function foo(Request $request, ClasseRepository $repoClass): void {
      $repoClass->find($request->request->get('classId'));
      ...
}
```

I would like to suggest you, to force the "classId" with one hardcoded.

```
$repoClass->find(1); // where 1 is a db you watched from db directly.
```

or

```
$repoCLass->findOneBy(['id'=> 1]); // where 1 is a well known unique identifier.
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're working with Symfony 4 is wrong.
Using directly `$_POST`, `$_SERVER`, etc is not recommanded.

This is how your `newcalendar` function should be :

```
public function newcalendar(Request $request, JobRepository $jobRepository, ClasseRepository $classeRepository) {
    $user=$this->getUser();
    if($user) {
        $currentStep=$user->getStep();

        // Custom query result could be optimised
        $jobId=$this->getJobId($user->getId())[0]['job_id'];

        // Use Job repository instead
        // $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Job::class);
        $job=$jobRepository->find($jobId);

        //Do not override your object, create a new varaible instead, or use getter directly
        // $job=$job->getName();
        if($currentStep < 10) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute("registration$currentStep");
        }
        if($job->getName() == 1 || $job->getName() == 'admin' || $job->getName() == "responsable de formation" || $job->getName() == "consseiller") {

            // Do not use $_SERVER directly, may cause issues with fragments
            // if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            if($request->isMethod('POST')) {

                // Same reason as $_SERVER
                $calendar=new Calendar();
                // $calendar->setStartDate($_POST['start']);
                $calendar->setStartDate($request->request->get('start'));
                // $calendar->setEndDate($_POST['end']);
                $calendar->setEndDate($request->request->get('end'));
                // $calendar->setEvent($_POST['event']);
                $calendar->setEvent($request->request->get('event'));
                // $classeId=$_POST['classeid'];
                $classeId=$request->request->get('classeid'); // Not used

                // Uncomment to check this value
                // dump($request->request->get('classeid'));
                // exit();

                // Use Classe repository instead
                // $repo=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Classe::class);
                // $classe=$repo->find($request->request->get('classeid'));
                $classe=$classeRepository->find($request->request->get('classeid'));

                //check if not null
                if($classe) {
                    $calendar->setClasse($classe);
                    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->persist($calendar);
                    $em->flush();
                }

                return $this->redirectToRoute('calendar');
            }

            return $this->render("formation/newcalendar.html.twig");
        } else {
            return $this->render("dashboard/index.html.twig", array(
                'controller_name'=>'DashboardController',
            ));
        }
    }

    // Could be handled by firewall
    return $this->redirectToRoute('security_login');
}
```

I left a few comments in the code.

Regarding the last line of this function, forcing login could be handle by Symfony firewall in `config/packages/security.yaml`

[Symfony Security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)
[Symfony access control](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html)

Please correct your code first.
You will notice that I left a dump in your code, uncomment it, and check that `classeid` is a valid value.

Looking at the Exception log, it's most likely the reason of your error

**[EDIT]**
Just to make sure, please run the following commands:

```
php bin/console make:migration
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Comment: thank you for the code review, the `classeid` is a valid value.

Comment: Then now, can you `exit();` your function, line by line, untill you get the error, it will pinpoint the line causing the error

Comment: the error come in this line :`$classe=$classeRepository->find($request->request->get('classeid'));` @Preciel

Comment: i already tried this command, this telling me `[WARNING] No database changes were detected.`

Comment: Then that your problem... Have you set you database in `.env` file?

Comment: yes the database in .env is already set. The find() method is working with other entity like Job so i don't think its because the database is not correctly set .

Comment: ah, my bad, missread the error message... Before the line causing the error, if you do this `dump($classeRepository); exit();`. Do you have anything? Or the varaible is null?

Comment: Then good... Meaning that the problem is really around that one request... Could it be that it can't fetch `Calendar` which is a OneToOne? Is there any value in Calendar?

Comment: yes calendar contain value but i don't think its because of calendar .

Comment: I don't think it's the case but, per chace, do the query appear in the doctrine tab of the profiler?

Comment: Yeah, this query is wrong... `t10` haven't been aliased. So it match nothing. It shoult be `t0.id`. The question is... How do we end up with this query... I'm suspecting that one relation is wrong, but can't figure in which way it's... :/

Answer (score 0):

please try to write a repository function. Just to understand the problem.

```
public function findThisDamnId(int $id): array    {

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.id > :val')
        ->setParameter('val',  $id)            
        ->getQuery();

    return $qb->execute();
}
```

or try the SQL standard

```
public function getThisDamnClassFromId(int $Id): array {
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

$sql = '
    SELECT * FROM classe c
    WHERE c.id > :val';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['id' => $id]);


return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: i already tried before the sql and i got my data but the problem is i need to get the object not the data .

Comment: it was just to be sure you were looking for valid data. 
Did you switch the $_POST with Request as I wrote?
Did you copy the Repository from another one?

Try to use make:repository 
and regenerate it 
(you need to delete it before)

Comment: yes i switched the $_POST. I deleted the classerepository file then i used php bin\console make:entity --regenerate  . But still have the error .@snipershady

Comment: could you post your class (please do not change anything), your repository class and your controller? (not just the use case)

Comment: the class : https://pastebin.com/r7hREPYD , the repository : https://pastebin.com/Mp118dQt , the controller : https://pastebin.com/q29UnyGd

Comment: @mohasalim Can you include the ORM annotation of the ID field of the related entities (Formation, Calendar, person)

Comment: @Jeroen formation : /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Classe", mappedBy="formation")
     */
    private $classe;

Comment: calendar :     /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\classe", inversedBy="calendar", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $classe;

Comment: person : /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Classe", mappedBy="responsable")
     */
    private $classes;

Comment: @mohasalim I meant the id fields of those entities, also update your question with the code, this is not readable